# Scrolling tabs in Android Froyo

Tags: android, tabs, components

The new Android Market (new sometime July 2011) has a couple of UI patterns that I like a lot. They seem to have half-copied the Windows Phone 7 tiles and also brought in a copy of the Action Bar component from Honeycomb and they have a very attractive tab bar just beneath that.

I know ActionBarSherlock does a pretty much perfect job of copying the action bar, but I was half-hoping someone knew of a ready-made solution for the tab bar. It should be simple enough to copy (just a few text labels that scroll sideways along with the views), but my time is short and experience limited.

Does anyone know about a good component or demo of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include [Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to your project . The widget you are looking for is

> **ViewPager**: A ViewGroup that manages the layout for the child views,
>   which the user can swipe between.
>
> PagerAdapter: An adapter that populates the ViewPager with the views
>   that represent each page.

Also check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) out from Android Dev